# VSCode PolyGlot configuration of dotnet

Tags: .net, visual-studio-code, polyglot-notebooks

I want to use the dotnet kernel within a PolyGlot Notebook in VSCode.

Even though I've installed dotnet version 8 the PolyGlot VSCode extension does not find the dotnet executable. How can configure the PolyGlot VSCode setting so that is finds the dotnet executable?

I tried this configuration but that didn't work (yet).

[image]

Comment: Issues should go to https://github.com/dotnet/interactive/issues